# WMI / WQL to query app pool start time / recycle time

Tags: c#, wmi

I've been trying to get the time or timestamp that a particular app pool had been started at and/or previously recycled at.  I see I can get the "uptime" of the "Default Web Site", but it doesn't appear it's possible on a specific app pool within this as I have yet to be able to find such a property value for this particular thing.  Does anyone know what to use to get at this?

Thanks

Comment: What code do you have so far?